# Is there any short way to add multiple items

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am adding data to table. Table looks like this:

[image]

I am getting multiple data from my JSP page that should be entered uniquely each time.
Means in table `prod_id` and `sc_id` will remain same for this request.
Suppose I am getting 3 items then I have to use 3 insert query that will pass each item one by one.

I am using JSP and sevlet for this.

So my question is that is there any unique or other way to do so using single INSERT statement?

Comment: normalize your table in such a way so that you will have distinct value in your parent table and keep reference in child table.

Comment: @Qadir - Sir, will you elaborate it ? I am not getting exactly what you want to tell.

Comment: When you say 'single query', do you mean 'single insert statement'?

Comment: @MartinWilson - Yes I am talking about single insert statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mMSQL you can insert multiple rows in one insert command:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

For example:

> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

Comment: Simply Great Sir. Thank You For the guidance. Helps me a lot.